# Prevent vertical scroll on body element when content added to div with height: 100%

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I don't want the scrollbar on body when I append some content above the scrollable div.

When I try to make div height less than 100% the scrollbar on the body dissapperars, but when I resize window the scrollbar on the body appears again.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fopeyvyd/1/) example of what I try to do.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
    html, body{
        height:100%;
        background:#eee;
    }
    #menu {
        background:#ccc;
        width:220px;
        height:100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #menu ul {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<p>
    some other content
    </p>
    <p>
    some other content
    </p>
    <p>
    some other content
    </p>
<div id="menu">
  
    <ul>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
        <li>owepwew</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**revised fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fopeyvyd/2/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 220px;
  flex: 1; /* use all available height */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>some other content</p>
  <p>some other content</p>
  <p>some other content</p>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
      <li>owepwew</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```